# UNIX sequence getting triggered in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a shell script which I am executing to deploy PL/SQL objects. packages/table scripts in an envirnoment.

Now when i am executing `sh XX_OBJECT.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/sh 
# Parameters to be accepted from command prompt
# Parameter 1 = Apps username/Password
# Parameter 2 = BOLINF username/Password
# Parameter 3 = Host name for the instance
# Parameter 4 = Port Number for the instance
# Parameter 5 = DB Name for the instance


#APPS_USER="$1"
#BOLINF_USER="$2"
#HOST_NAME="$3"
#PORT_NUMBER="$4"
#DB_NAME="$5"

LOGFILE=XXHCM_STAG`date +%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S`.log
LOG_PATH=`echo $CUR_DIR/$LOG_FILE`

#APPS_USERNAME=$(echo $APPS_USER|cut -f "1" -d /)
#APPS_PWD=$(echo $APPS_USER|cut -f "2" -d /)

#-
#-  reading program parameters
#-

echo "Enter APPS User: "

read APPS

echo "Enter APPS Password: "

stty -echo

read APPS_PWD

stty echo


echo "Enter Install Server (SID): "

read SID



APPS_USER="$APPS/$APPS_PWD@$SID"


APPS_USERNAME=$(echo $APPS_USER|cut -f "1" -d /)

APPS_PWD=$(echo $APPS_USER|cut -f "2" -d /)


echo "Starting installation of XXHCM_OBJECTS - XXHCM_OBJECTS ..."
echo "Starting installation of XXHCM_OBJECTS - XXHCM_OBJECTS ..."    "">>$LOGFILE
echo   "">>$LOGFILE

echo   "">>$LOGFILE
echo "Copying Files To Appropriate Directories ..."
echo "Copying Files To Appropriate Directories ..."  "">>$LOGFILE
echo   "">>$LOGFILE

cp *.ldt $XXHCM_TOP/install

cp *.sql $XXHCM_TOP/sql 

cp *.pks $XXHCM_TOP/sql 

cp *.pkb $XXHCM_TOP/sql 

cp *.ctl $XXHCM_TOP/bin

cp *.prog $XXHCM_TOP/bin

echo   "">>$LOGFILE


echo   "">>$LOGFILE
echo "Files copied successfully !!! "
echo "Files copied successfully !!! "    "">>$LOGFILE
echo   "">>$LOGFILE

echo "Changing permissions ... "     "">>$LOGFILE
chmod 777 *.*
echo "Changed permissions ... "     "">>$LOGFILE

echo    "">>$LOGFILE
echo "Creating Custom Package, Synonyms and Grants..."   "">>$LOGFILE
echo "Creating Custom Package, Synonyms and Grants..."
echo    "">>$LOGFILE

if sqlplus $APPS_USER @I_table_creation.sql
then
    echo "Custom itables created successfully in APPS schema"     "">>$LOGFILE
    echo "Custom itables created successfully in APPS schema" 
else
    echo "Error in creating custom  itables in APPS schema"     "">>$LOGFILE
    echo "Error in creating Custom itables  in APPS schema" 
fi

if sqlplus $APPS_USER @insert_entities.sql
then
    echo "Insert data into entities table in APPS schema"     "">>$LOGFILE
    echo "Insert data into entities table in APPS schema"
else
    echo "Error in Insert data into entities table in APPS schema"     "">>$LOGFILE
    echo "Error in Insert data into entities table in APPS schema" 
fi

if sqlplus $APPS_USER @insert_fields.sql
then
    echo "Insert data into insert_fields table in APPS schema"     "">>$LOGFILE
    echo "Insert data into insert_fields table in APPS schema"
else
    echo "Error in Insert data into insert_fields table in APPS schema"     "">>$LOGFILE
    echo "Error in Insert data into insert_fields table in APPS schema" 
fi


if sqlplus $APPS_USER @xx_cmp_thread.pks
then
    echo "Package specification for package xx_cmp_thread created in APPS schema"     "">>$LOGFILE
    echo "Package specification for package xx_cmp_thread created in APPS schema"
else
    echo "Error in creating Package specification"     "">>$LOGFILE
    echo "Error in creating Package specification" 
fi

if sqlplus $APPS_USER @xx_cmp_thread.pkb
then
    echo "Package specification for package xx_cmp_thread created in APPS schema"     "">>$LOGFILE
    echo "Package specification for package xx_cmp_thread created in APPS schema"
else
    echo "Error in creating Package specification"     "">>$LOGFILE
    echo "Error in creating Package specification" 
fi
echo    "">>$LOGFILE
echo "Package, Synonyms,grants and Tables created successfully"   "">>$LOGFILE
echo "Package, Synonyms,grants and Tables created successfully"
echo  "">>$LOGFILE


echo "Installation completed for XXHCM_OBJECTS - XXHCM_OBJECTS"
echo "Installation completed for XXHCM_OBJECTS - XXHCM_OBJECTS"     "">>$LOGFILE
# *****************************************************************************
# End of Script
# *****************************************************************************
```

While executing the `sh XX_OBJECT.sh` after the insert_fields.sql is executed in Putty i am getting sequence in output like :

```
29
30
31
32
34
```

Dont know why is the sequence getting triggered out of nowhere

Comment: Well, it must be something coming out of insert_entities.sql or insert_fields.sql. What do those look like?

Comment: @JeffY- These are alter scripts. I removed these still getting this sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen something similar to this before when you don't exit from your sql script correctly. I believe they're just line numbers that are output from sqlplus.You most likely want to make sure that you have a proper exit statement at the end of your scripts that looks something like:

```
exit
/
```